# execute script on SSH exit

Tags: ssh, scripts

is it possible to execute an shell script when i'm exiting a SSH session?
I want to execute script to disable a service when exiting

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is `bash`, one way could be to use commands in `~/.bash_logout`. From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash.1):

```
When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file 
~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
```

SSH runs a login shell, so when it exits `.bash_logout` should be run. You can check whether it is an SSH session by testing the value of the `SSH_TTY` variable. So you can edit (or create) `~/.bash_logout` containing, for example:

```
if [[ -n $SSH_TTY ]]
then
    stop your service
fi
```

Comment: Cool, however, doesn't work when the connection is broken.